# How can I refresh files that have been changed outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was editing a file simultaneously in both Visual Studio & Notepad++ (I know, I know, it's a silly thing to do, I know). After saving changes made with Notepad++, how can I refresh Visual Studio to see those changes?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I verify that?

Comment: Yes. The file appears in my soliton, under my project. I have checked it's full path, by right-clicking and selecting properties, to make sure it's the same as the one in Notepad++.

Answer (score 5):

To refresh the change file automatically, we need to change a setting.
Open Visual Studio, choose 'Tools' from menu bar <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
Go to Options > Environment > Documents. Enable these two options

1. Detect when file is changed outside the environment
2. Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes

[image: visual_studio_required_options]

The second choice is optional. Press OK. Restart Visual Studio if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me. I notice that the second option, "Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes," is worded slightly differently than my "Auto-load changes, if saved" option. Perhaps this is an issue specific to my version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @LongTP5 Try to enable this: Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Track changes.

Comment: It's already enabled. Still no change.

Comment: Merely having these settings on does not reload the file; when you try to save, visual studio still says "The file on disk was changed but was not reloaded," etc. -- the question of what you do to immediately reload the file still stands

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the file doesn't automatically reload, you can close the tab and use one of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853038/reopen-last-closed-tab-in-visual-studio) to reopen it. This will refresh the file contents.

I bound `Window > Restore Closed Tab` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>, so I can close the tab and immediately reopen it quickly.